# Three JS render a plane, from one point to another

Tags: three.js

I am trying to render a planeGemetry which connects 2 points in space...
Before I was having a line, which worked excellent by adding 2 verticles to specific coordinates.

```
laserGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(playerModel.position.x, playerModel.position.y, playerModel.position.z));
laserGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(module.currentTarget.positionX * distanceAmplifier,module.currentTarget.positionY * distanceAmplifier,module.currentTarget.positionZ * distanceAmplifier));
```

Not sure how to do the same thing with planeGeometry unfortunatelly.
Is there any way in doing this ?

Comment: Will the two points be on the corners of the resulting plane, or the edges? If it's the edges, where exactly will they be? How will the plane be rotated? You need 3 points to orient a plane in 3D space, not two.

Comment: The plane will be few pixels wide and long depending on the distance between the points. The edges should be connected with the meshes and the plane needs to be updated on requestanimationFrame since the player or the other object will move around.

Comment: Try drawing a picture of your intended behavior, that will make it more clear.

Comment: http://oi66.tinypic.com/v33t3n.jpg So the blue line needs to be replaced with a plane instead, the blue line gets redrawed over and over again right not in order to update it's position when the player is moving